# CodedUI tests failing due to missing assembly reference?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, coded-ui-tests

I have a coded UI test built with VS2010 for TFS2010 running on machine A.  I have a test agent installed on machine A that the tests run on successfully.  My testsettings file>Roles is set to RemoteExecution because these codedUI tests ALWAYS need to be run on machine A.  The file always says "connected to the controller" that I specified.

I check the code into the build server (machine B), and it fails.  With copy local set to false on the codedUI assemblies, the build fails with an error:

> "Not runnable: Failed to initialize the unit test extension
>   'urn:CodedUITest': A unit test extension is not registered for the
>   following attribute:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute."

In the application logs on machine B, I get this:

> (QTAgent32.exe, PID 5308, Thread 8) GetCollectorType: Failed to get
>   type for Collector
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.SystemInfo.SystemInfoDataCollector,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.SystemInfo,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a':
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.SystemInfo,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.SystemInfo,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName)    at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.ExecutionPluginManager.GetCollectorType(String
>   collectorTypeName, Exception& loadException)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

And in the Administration console I get this:

> Following error encountered while reading sqm registry entry:
>   TF255003: The installation path cannot be found for the following
>   feature: ApplicationTier. Either the feature is not installed, or you
>   must use a different installation path.

With copy local set to true on the coded UI assemblies, I don't get any error in the Build Explorer in VS, but the build fails and says 0/0 tests run.  In the application log on machine B, I get:

> The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> (MSTest.exe, PID 5544, Thread 1) Exception thrown when enumerating
>   assembly:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Exceptions.EqtDataException: Unable
>   to load the test container
>   'C:\Builds\1\Project\Binaries\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. Error details:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   **'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Vsip**, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.AssemblyEnumerator.EnumerateAssembly(IWarningHandler
>   warningHandler, String location, ProjectData projectData, ObjectHandle
>   assemblyResolverWrapper)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.AssemblyEnumerator.EnumerateAssembly(IWarningHandler
>   warningHandler, String location, ProjectData projectData, ObjectHandle
>   assemblyResolverWrapper)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAttributeEnumerator.Read(ITestTypeExtensionClientSidesProvider
>   provider, IWarningHandler warningHandler, String assemblyFileName,
>   ProjectData projectData, TestRunConfiguration testRunConfiguration)

Machine B does have VS2010 express installed.

What else do I need to do to get this building on Machine B (build machine), but tests running on Machine A (with the test agent)?  What else can I do to diagnose this?

UPDATE: I tried manually copying the qualitytools.vsip dll into the project and referencing it that way with copy local set to true, but now I'm back to getting

> "Failed to initialize the unit test extension 'urn:CodedUITest': A
>   unit test extension is not registered for the following attribute:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly make a check the project property that the target framework is not set to .NET framework 4 client profile. Instead set to .Net framework 4 (without client profile)

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CodedUITestProject1.Libraries
{
    class generic
    {
        public static BrowserWindow mParentWindow { get; set; }
        public static BrowserWindow ParentWindow
        {
            get
            {
                if(mParentWindow==null)
                { mParentWindow = TopParentWindow(); }
                return mParentWindow;
            }
        }

        public static BrowserWindow TopParentWindow()
        {
            BrowserWindow window = new BrowserWindow();
            window.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ClassName]=BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser.ToString();
            return window;
        }


        public enum PropertyType
        { Id,
          Name,
          ClassName,
          InnerText,
          TagInstance
        }

        public static void EnterText<T>(PropertyType type,string propvalue,string text) where T:HtmlControl
        {
            HtmlControl genericControl = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { ParentWindow });
            if (type==PropertyType.Id)
            {
                genericControl.SearchProperties[HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id] = propvalue;

            }

            else if (type == PropertyType.Id)
            {
                genericControl.SearchProperties[HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id] = propvalue;

            }
            Keyboard.SendKeys(genericControl, text);
        }

        public static void ClickLink<T>(PropertyType type, string propvalue) where T : HtmlControl
        {
            HtmlControl genericControl = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { ParentWindow });
            if (type == PropertyType.Id)
            {
                genericControl.SearchProperties[HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id] = propvalue;

            }

            else if (type == PropertyType.Id)
            {
                genericControl.SearchProperties[HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id] = propvalue;

            }
            //Assert.IsTrue(genericControl.WaitForControlExist(40000));
            Mouse.Click(genericControl);

        }

         public static Boolean ExistLink<T>(PropertyType type, string propvalue) where T : HtmlControl
        {
            HtmlControl genericControl = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { ParentWindow });
            if (type == PropertyType.Id)
            {
                genericControl.SearchProperties[HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id] = propvalue;

            }

            else if (type == PropertyType.Id)
            {
                genericControl.SearchProperties[HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id] = propvalue;

            }
            try
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(genericControl.WaitForControlExist(4000));
                return true;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            //Mouse.Click(genericControl);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Solution 1:  Replace the name as that seen in pop UP. Might be this code can help clicking it

    WinWindow pop = new WinWindow(null);
                pop.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Message from webpage", "ClassName", "#32770");

    ‘Windows Internet Explorer
                pop.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
                pop.DrawHighlight();

//------------
“Usinng MSTEST.exe to generate result”

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE>MSTest /testcontainer:
D:\Practise\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITestProject1\bin\Debu
g\CodedUITestProject1.dll /test:CodedUITestMethod1 /resultsfile:D:\SachintestRes
.trx


 public void CodedUITestMethod1()
        {
            // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
            // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
            string testcase = " /testcontainer:" + "D:\\Practise\\CodedUITestProject1\\CodedUITestProject1\\CodedUITestProject1\\bin\\Debug\\CodedUITestProject1.dll /test:CodedUITestMethod1 /resultsfile:D:\\SachintestResAut.trx";

            string Path = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest";

            Process myProcess = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path, testcase);
            myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
                myProcess.Start();
                myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

                WinText text = new WinText(pop);

                text.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Some Name");
                String msg = text.GetProperty("DisplayText").ToString();

                if (msg.Contains("Data saved."))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("System is displaying " + msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("System is displaying " + msg);
                }

                WinButton ok = new WinButton(pop);
                ok.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
                ok.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "OK");
                Mouse.Click(ok);

    Solution 2: Try the Browser Dialog Actions like OK,Cancel,Close .May be it can be helpful. PFB snapshot below.

    try
                {
                    BrowserWindow browserWindow = new BrowserWindow();
                    browserWindow.PerformDialogAction(BrowserDialogAction.Ok);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // If a popup does not exists and an error is thrown, continue...
                    Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;
                }
```

//C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE>MSTest /testcontainer:
D:\Practise\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITestProject1\bin\Debu
g\CodedUITestProject1.dll /test:CodedUITestMethod1 /resultsfile:D:\SachintestRes
.trx

```
 public void CodedUITestMethod1()
        {
            // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
            // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
            string testcase = " /testcontainer:" + "D:\\Practise\\CodedUITestProject1\\CodedUITestProject1\\CodedUITestProject1\\bin\\Debug\\CodedUITestProject1.dll /test:CodedUITestMethod1 /resultsfile:D:\\SachintestResAut.trx";

            string Path = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest";

            Process myProcess = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path, testcase);
            myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
                myProcess.Start();
                myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```